# Apache Location match ignored in favour of Directory match

Tags: php, apache, rest, security, httpd.conf

I have a pre-existing PHP-based web application that is secured by an IP whitelist, and I am attempting to roll out a tool that will need to bypass that list, but I want to continue to secure it so that it only has access to a specific URL, over a specific method, and via a specific browser agent; I wrote the following configuration for my Apache 2.4 configuration file thinking it would do this:

```
<Location "/index.php/api/specific-end-point">
    SetEnvIf User-Agent "MyCustomBrowser" Approved
    <RequireAll>
        Require method POST
        Require env Approved
    </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

However all of my requests are returned with a 403 Forbidden error code.
This code block appears to do very little, and having experimented with it, it will not even allow me to expose that path with just a single simple *Require ip x.x.x.x* directive.

The IP address whitelist consists of a directory directive on the webroot similar to this:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.1
Allow from 192.168.1.2
...
</Directory>
```

The applications file **index.php** exists within the **/var/www/html** directory which has the following configuration:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I assume that one of those other configuration blocks is causing my 403 response but I don't know what I can do to the configuration to apply all of my security requirements, block everyone not in the whitelist generally, but allow my tool access to POST to my specific endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I built a lab environment to simulate the third-party application mentioned and have come to the conclusion that the IP whitelist functionality was put together in the HTTPD 2.2 syntax which is enabled by [mod_access_compat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html).

I was able to resolve this by stripping that IP whitelisting from the `<Directory "/var/www">` section and converting into the following HTTPD 2.4 syntax block:

```
<Location "/">
AllowOverride None
<RequireAny>
Require ip 192.168.1.1
Require ip 192.168.1.2
...
</RequireAny>
</Location>
```

With that in place, the code I originally posted in the question, the `<Location "/index.php/api/specific-end-point">` block, looked to work successfully.